# Oracle10 and JDBC: how to make CHAR ignore trailing spaces at comparision?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, char

I have a query that has

> ... WHERE PRT_STATUS='ONT' ...

The prt_status field is defined as CHAR(5) though. So it's always padded with spaces. The query matches nothing as the result. To make this query work I have to do

> ... WHERE rtrim(PRT_STATUS)='ONT'

which does work.

That's annoying.

At the same time, a couple of pure-java DBMS clients (Oracle SQLDeveloper and AquaStudio) I have do NOT have a problem with the first query, they return the correct result. TOAD has no problem either.

I presume they simply put the connection into some compatibility mode (e.g. ANSI), so the Oracle knows that CHAR(5) expected to be compared with no respect to trailing characters.

**How can I do it with Connection objects I get in my application?**

**UPDATE** I cannot change the database schema.

**SOLUTION** It was indeed the way Oracle compares fields with passed in parameters.

When bind is done, the string is passed via PreparedStatement.setString(), which sets type to VARCHAR, and thus Oracle uses unpadded comparision -- and fails.

I tried to use setObject(n,str,Types.CHAR). Fails. Decompilation shows that Oracle ignores CHAR and passes it in as a VARCHAR again.

The variant that finally works is

```
setObject(n,str,OracleTypes.FIXED_CHAR);
```

It makes the code not portable though.

The UI clients succeed for a different reason -- they use character literals, not binding. When I type PRT_STATUS='ONT', 'ONT' is a literal, and as such compared using padded way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that [Oracle compares `CHAR` values using blank-padded comparison semantics.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c13datyp.htm#701)

From [Datatype Comparison Rules](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements2a.htm#46504),

> Oracle uses blank-padded comparison
>   semantics only when both values in the
>   comparison are either expressions of
>   datatype CHAR, NCHAR, text literals,
>   or values returned by the USER
>   function.

In your example, is `'ONT'` passed as a bind parameter, or is it built into the query textually, as you illustrated?  If a bind parameter, then make sure that it is bound as type `CHAR`.  Otherwise, verify the client library version used, as really old versions of Oracle (e.g. v6) will have different comparison semantics for `CHAR`.

Comment: Hmm... that makes sense. JDBC's setString uses VARCHAR to bind a string parameter. Not sure if I can use this to solve the problem, but at least it becomes clearer now.

Comment: You probably right: "Oracle uses nonpadded comparison semantics whenever one or both values in the comparison have the datatype VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2". I need to do a test to check it.

Comment: Thanks, Vlad! See my solution above.

Comment: Glad the problem is fixed! V.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change your database table, you can modify your query.

Some alternatives for RTRIM:

> .. WHERE PRT_STATUS like 'ONT%' ...
>
> .. WHERE PRT_STATUS = 'ONT  ' ... -- 2 white spaces behind T
>
> .. WHERE PRT_STATUS = rpad('ONT',5,' ') ...

Answer (score 0):

I would change CHAR(5) column into varchar2(5) in db.

Comment: Out of question. DB doesn't belong to our group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast to char operation in your query:

```
... WHERE PRT_STATUS=cast('ONT' as char(5))
```

Or in more generic JDBC way:

```
... WHERE PRT_STATUS=cast(? as char(5))
```

And then in your JDBC code do use `statement.setString(1, "ONT");`