# ColdFusion 9: how to pad list values with spaces

Tags: coldfusion, padding

In the database, style_id columns is defined as CHAR(14).
I need to be able to pad values in the list to 14 with spaces.
How do I go about it?
Thanks,

```
<cfset style_list = replace(#FORM.style_id#," ","","all")>

select *
from T
where 
    <cfif IsDefined("form.style_id") and form.style_id is not "">
        style_id in 
                    (
                        <cfqueryparam
                            value="#UCASE(style_list)#"
                            cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
                            list="yes" />
                    ) 
 </cfif>
```

Comment: Pad it in the database or in your output? Database, you can't because it's a `varchar()`. You'd have to switch it to a `char()` datatype, which would be the easiest if you can. Also, do you want it padded on the left or on the right?

Comment: Also, what values do you want to pad with?

Comment: Duh, I apparently can't read. You said it was a `CHAR(14)` in your question. What are some of the values you'd be working with?

Comment: Also, look at your `cfif` nesting, becuase if `form.style_id` isn't defined or is empty, your query will fail as invalid. And, I'd recommend `structKeyExist(FORM,"style_id")` over `isDefined()`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to pad the values? Should work without any padding using `cfsqltype=cf_sql_char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you need to pad the values? It should work fine without any padding, using cfsqltype CF_SQL_**CHAR**.  Perhaps it's not working as expected because the [left side of the comparison (column) is type CHAR while the right (cfqueryparam) is type VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/603330/8895292)?

I tested your query and it worked fine with CF 9,0,2,282541 and SQL Server. It also worked correctly with CF 9.0.2 and Oracle 12G. CFQueryparam seemed to handle things automatically.

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE someTable(style_id char(14))
INSERT INTO someTable VALUES ('abc'),('efg          ')
```

**CF:**

```
<!--- worked with both CF_SQL_VARCHAR and CF_SQL_CHAR ---> 
<cfset style_list = "abc,efg">
<cfquery name="qTest" datasource="YourDSN">
    SELECT *
    FROM   SomeTable
    WHERE  style_id in 
                    (   <cfqueryparam
                            value="#UCASE(style_list)#"
                            cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" 
                            list="yes" />
                    ) 
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#qTest#">
```

**Results:**

```
RESULTSET   
query
       STYLE_ID
1      abc  
2      efg
```

Comment: I changed it to cfsqltype="cf_sql_char", but it still did not work for me. I am using Oracle. The column defined as CHAR(14) and style_id values in the table are 14 chars long. `select style_id, length(style_id) 
from style
where rownum < 5;` returns **1001W          14**

Comment: Which driver are you using in the dsn? I'll try it with Oracle 12.

Comment: What do you expect it to return? If your `char(14)` field in Oracle holds `"1001W         "`, then that should return 14 for Oracle`length()` for a `char()` field. What is it that you are trying to do? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm >> 'If char has datatype CHAR, then the length includes all trailing blanks.`

Comment: Oracle `char()` columns are right-padded to the specified length on storage, but are trimmed on retrieval unless specifically set to return the full length. But `length()` on a `char()` will return the entire length of the column. In this case 14.

Comment: @user1549571 ^^^^

Comment: Shawn, if database column is configured as CHAR() , then it stores data padded to the length of that char (in my case 14). I am running CF9 and connecting to Oracle 9.2.0.8 I can trim it: ... where trim(style_id) = ... ,but it will kill the index on this column. I will play with LJustify() next. Thanks

Comment: @user1549571 - I tested this with CF9.0.2 and Oracle 12 (CHAR(14)) and it works fine without any trimming.  I suppose it's possible Oracle 9 behaves differently, but ... seems VERY odd the driver would force you to pad the input. **How exactly did you verify the spaces are what's causing the issue and not something else, like say upper/lower case differences?**

Answer (score 1):

Do the opposite. Trim the contents of of the `style_id` column in your SQL statement so that you can batter match the contents of `style_list`.

Comment: Not sure about CF9, but it works just fine under CF11 using `cfsqltype="cf_sql_char"` (no trimming of columns or padding of values).

Comment: If I trim style on database side, database will not use index on that column

Comment: True. Though why do you need to trim at all? In my tests with 9.0.2, it wasn't neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ljustify](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/ljustify.html) or [rjustify](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/rjustify.html) to pad a string with spaces.

You could pre-process the list with a loop:

```
<cfset padded_list=""/>
<cfloop list="#style_list#" item="style">
  <cfset padded_list=listappend(padded_list, rjustify(style, 14))/>
</cfloop>
```

If you're using a more recent version of ColdFusion, or a shim, you may also have [listmap](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listmap.html), which is less ugly:

```
<cfset style_list=listmap(style_list, function(style) { return rjustify(style, 14); })/>
```

Comment: And today in "functions you never heard of": lJustify and rJustify! Learning never stops.